# New line fails to appear in strings within Canvas

Tags: javascript, string, canvas, newline

Every tutorials and helps I've ever read tells that in Javascript, `\n` is the basic "newline character", though it completely fails to appear on my system. I've tried various configurations: `\r\n`, separating \n with `+`, puttng string into a new variable, and so on, but string is not written into a new line, whatever I do.

I use fillText() method of an HTML canvas, maybe this is the reason, especially because the problem occurs both on Opera, Firefox and Chrome. FillStyle property is simply "white".

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no multi-line support for `fillText()` unfortunately, this is likely the cause of your issue.

In order to simulate it you'd have to use `fillText()` multiple times, here's a JSfiddle showing an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/BaG4J/1/

Comment: Ouch...it's a bit inconvenient. Thank you anyway, I'm less stressful now at least.

Comment: Yes it is! Glad that I was able to help